# ipython installed but not running on OSX mavericks

Tags: python, macos

I'm running Mavericks with conda and pip as python package managers. I'm trying to run ipython from the terminal (bash) but the system just isn't having it. Whenever I try to run it, I get the following error thrown at me:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2716, in <module>

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 685, in require
    def __getstate__(self):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
    The `plugin_env` should be an ``Environment`` instance that contains
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: ipython==2.0.0-dev
```

---

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the software several times, but it doesn't seem to work.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know. I'm trying to get iJulia up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the similar problem. Here is the solution that I found and works for me.

```
# refresh the ipython installation
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ipython && pip uninstall ipython -y && pip install ipython

# remove the warning startup
rm -rf ~/.ipython
```

Hope it may help you.

Cheers,

RL